# Should tags be singular or plural?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we use

- [solver](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solver) or [solvers](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solvers)?
- [constraint](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraint) or [constraints](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraints)?
- [heuristic](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heuristic) or [heuristics](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heuristics)?

There is discussion of this on other SE sites and their metas, but no clear consensus as far as I can tell.

Whichever type we prefer, should the other be allowed, and made a synonym?

Comment: The poll got deleted. Please voice your opinions by posting and/or voting for answers.

Comment: I prefer the pluralized versions.

Comment: Please consider adding Tags: [tag-creation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-creation/info), [ambiguous-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ambiguous-tags/info), and ***maybe*** [tag-synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-synonyms/info) - and at some point one of us copy/paste the excerpt/wiki.

Answer (score 7):

### I would prefer the plural

This is also the way Wikipedia lists categories. For example, looking up [*heuristic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) reveals the categories: *heuristics*, *problem solving methods*.

While it is no big deal, using the plural for the examples given by the OP reads a bit more natural in my opinion. I am not sure we need to make the singular form a synonym and would propose to not go that extra mile.

Answer (score 1):

Previously we had a problem with tags that [differed by only a hyphen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147233/282094), but [that problem was coded away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107002/282094). With singular vs. plural it's more difficult to code a solution, so it's important to create the initial tag appropriately to avoid lengthy cleanups in the future.

Searching [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=tags%20singular%20plural) for guidance may be a challenge but the [extra work involved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6752/282094) for leaving it open is clear; it's resulted in creation of the <kbd>[clean-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/clean-up/info)</kbd> tag and a few questions:

- [Should tags use dashes camel case or underscores? Should they be singular or plural?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19163/282094)
- [Tagging as singular or plural](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41501/282094)

Generally, under the rules of [specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specificity_(linguistics)), [collective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun#English) and [count nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun), [measure words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_word), etc., the [grammatical number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Singular_versus_plural) would be [unmarked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_(linguistics)); the [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number)) is inferred by the usage, unless the word [always takes the singular ***or*** plural form](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/plurals.htm) (examples: glasses, pants, or scissors - the singular and plural forms have different meanings).

See also English Language and Usage - Search <kbd>[grammatical-number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-number)</kbd> tags.

The policy on main Meta and Stack Overflow is:

- [Merge singular and plural tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6752/282094)
- [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/3648282)

If there's any advantageous reason to be different another answer should explain that.